# Using affordably as an adverb

Tags: adverbs

I wish to write:

> The product cost is affordably accessible to all consumer types.

I mean to say:

> The product cost is so affordable, any type of consumer can afford it.

1. Can I use "affordably" as an adverb in this sense?
2. Does what I've written semantically match what I mean to say?

Comment: Your first sentence is using the *adverb* (not adjective) "affordably" to modify the adjective "accessible".

Comment: **The product cost is so affordable, any type of consumer can afford it.** This is almost a tautology, with the repetition of the word affordable, since affordable (in advertising writing at least) means "cheap" without sounding "cheap".  And "product cost" is not necessary either, since in this context it seems redundant. The implication of "affordable" is that it is value-for-money, but it is very vague and can't be quantified. I would suggest: "The product is so low-cost that it will suit any budget.", or something similarly simple.

Comment: @HotLicks Thanks for the correction. Question edited.

Comment: Can anyone clarify if "affordably accessible" is constructed correctly (see question number 2)?

Comment: In terms of adverb-adjective it is grammatical, like "brightly coloured", but it is an awkward expression in English, and semi-redundant: if something is affordable, then it is also accessible to people on a low budget (or at least the advertiser would like people to think so).

Comment: @Cargill- Did you mean a redundant pleonasm that unnecessarily repeated a tautology that had already been stated and reiterated in superfluity? Did I miss any? ;-)

Comment: I meant to say, now, and in the fullness of time, that notwithstanding a proclivity to be verbose, let me just say that I feel it must be said that yes, the affordable accessibility of the said product, given its low product cost per unit item, is cheap and therefore affordable for those on a low budget who don't have a lot of income, and can't spend a great deal on this product unless it's sold at an affordable cost per unit.

Comment: <blowing mashed potatoes out of my nose> Now back to dinner. Thank you.

Comment: @Cargill When yourself and Mark are done measuring the analogical inches of your respective lexica, please add a composite of your comments as an answer to allow to select it.. :-P

Comment: @MarkHubbard A "redundant pleonasm"? All pleonasms are redundant. Your use of the word "redundant" as an adjective of "pleonasm" is therefore pleonastic.PLEONCEPTION!

Comment: @ClarusDignus- Thank you for joining the fun! :-) I can't wait for an opportunity to use "pleonception" in conversation -- perhaps at Christmas Eve dinner. However, I believe every serious question deserves a serious answer, so I will attempt to construct one now.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1. Yes, you can use **"affordably"** as an adverb in that sense. However, the sentence would be improved if you wrote, **"The product is affordably accessible to all consumer types."** (Please note that I have deleted the word **"cost,"** which is redundant in your original example.)
2. Yes, with the small change suggested above, what you have written semantically matches what you mean to say. Good job.

Comment: Thanks for answering my question on a point-by-point basis (and for introducing me to the concepts of pleons and tautologies).